# IIS - Cannot create ActiveX component

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm trying to run a COM component from my Asp.Net app on IIS server, but getting error:

> Cannot create ActiveX component

So I'm calling it like that in the code, passing login on the end

```
gobjDaabOLE = CreateObject("Daab.Application." & DaabLogin)
```

Login is actually a profile name that the Daab app use.
So it all works on the local machine but when I run it through and IIS app is coming with the error.

I believe the problem is related to Daab app configuration on IIS. Every time I login to the IIS server using different credential and open Daab app it has default configuration. So I need to configure it (add location of the profile).

So now if ApplicationPool is running the app it gives me an error as there is default configuration. There is no option to globally set up the Daab app. How can I go around that? What login is Application pool using? Can I log in as that user to configure the app? Is it possible to impersonate Application pool to use one of the login already configured?

The configuration is recorded in HKEY_CURRENT_USER in registry, but nothing in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. I have tried manually add it, didnt work.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You can learn some basics from https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Comment: Nice read, but does't explain how I can login to session 0 to configure my app

Comment: Ok, I resolved. Impersonation worked